# How to add more than one button in card resoponse in dialogflow using nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, dialogflow-es

I am trying to add more than one button in facebook messenger card response using dialogflow nodejs. I am able to do that from dialogflow console but not with the code

```
const welcome = (agent) => { agent.add(`Welcome to my Khoon hazir. It is an online blood bank. How may i help you?`);
    agent.add(new Card({
        title: `Khoon hazir`,
        imageUrl: 'https://images.pexels.com/photos/355296/pexels-photo-355296.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500',
        text: `This is an online Blood bank, aim to save lives`,
        buttonText: 'Need Blood',
        buttonUrl: 'https://www.facebook.com/khoon.hazir/'
    }));        
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created this unofficial fork that support multi buttons:
https://github.com/fabio-C/dialogflow-fulfillment-nodejs

**Tested Only of Facebook/Messanger Platform.**

Answer (score 0):

According to this https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-fulfillment-nodejs/blob/master/src/rich-responses/card-response.js. You cannot do that directly. You have to edit the library code to do that. Just edit the code between line numbers 274 and 279 to support the multiple buttons.